# VScode with Jupiter Notebook: "Export failed [Error: Importing notebooks requires Jupyter nbconvert to be installed.]"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using the Jupiter Notebook in VSCode, and while trying to export from .ipynb to .py through the specific "Export" button in VSCode, an error comes up asking me to install `nbconvert`. I have installed it outside of the venv in which I currently work on this .ipynb file through the command `pip install nbconvert`, but this issue is still present.

Should I install it again in the venv? Is that going to cause some kind of problem? The following lines of texts are from the Output panel of VSCode for Jupiter. Thanks.

```
Info 2021-08-13 18:24:39: Process Execution: > ~/Desktop/Courses/Python/Python/bin/python -c "import nbconvert"
> ~/Desktop/Courses/Python/Python/bin/python -c "import nbconvert"
Error 2021-08-13 18:24:39: Export failed [Error: Importing notebooks requires Jupyter nbconvert to be installed.
    at u.getExportInterpreter (/Users/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1195043623/out/client/extension.js:37:579885)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async b.export (/Users/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1195043623/out/client/extension.js:54:260397)
    at async m.export (/Users/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1195043623/out/client/extension.js:37:291492)
    at async _executeContributedCommand (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:85:109243)]
```

Comment: Have you installed it in the `venv` virtual environment? Does it work?

Comment: No, I haven't, since I'm not sure having it installed both outside and inside the venv at the same time would cause harm. Should I uninstall it from outside, and then install it in the venv?